# Use values stored in variables with jQuery.Keyframes

Tags: html, jquery, css-animations, jquery-animate, keyframe

I want to change my animations using jQuery and found this helpful [tutorial](https://github.com/Keyframes/jQuery.Keyframes). This works -

```
 $.keyframe.define([{
     name: 'slidein',
           
        from:   {'margin-left': '100%'},
        to:   {'margin-left': '10%'}
       }]);
```

But instead of providing a fixed percentage or px value, I want to use a variable which has a px or percentage value stored in it. I have tried all the below and none worked

```
   // to:   {'margin-left': bigSlide.width}
   // to:   {'margin-left': 'bigSlide.width'}
   // to:   {'margin-left': calc(bigSlide.width)}
   // to:   {'margin-left': 'calc(bigSlide.width)'}
   // to:   {'margin-left': (100px+630px)}
   // to:   {'margin-left': calc(100px+630px)},
   // to:   {'margin-left':'calc(100vw - 800px)'}
```

}]);

I tried options such as `calc(100px+630px)` to just see if I could get calc working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a value in the form - to: {'margin-left': bigSlide.width + 'px'}. Use concatenation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your variable in a template literal like this:

```
\`${variableName}\`
```

This will make it read as a string with whatever value is in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Maxim G for your above suggestion. I got this solution working.

```
$.keyframe.define([{
      name: 'slidein',
    
      from:   {'margin-left': '100%'},
      to:   {'margin-left':bigSlide.width + bigSlide.getBoundingClientRect().left+'px'}

    }])
```